# Need to speed-up this Python script - i think the StringIO is very SLOW

Tags: python, string, performance, kml

This is working but is SLOW.

I have written a custom .py to convert .gpx to .kml. Its working like i need but it is sooooo slow: For a small .gpx of 477k, it is writing a 207k .kml file that takes 198 seconds to complete! thats absurd and i haven't even got to a meaty .gpx size yet.

My hunch is that it is the `stringIO.stringIO(x)` that's so slow. Any ideas how to speed it up?

Thanks in anticipation.

Here are the key snips ONLY:

```
f = open(fileName, "r")
x = f.read()
x = re.sub(r'\n', '', x, re.S) #remove any newline returns
name = re.search('<name>(.*)</name>', x, re.S)
print "Attachment name (as recorded from GPS device): " + name.group(1)

x = re.sub(r'<(.*)<trkseg>', '', x, re.S)  #strip header
x = x.replace("</trkseg></trk></gpx>",""); #strip footer
x = x.replace("<trkpt","\n<trkpt"); #make the file in lines
x = re.sub(r'<speed>(.*?)</speed>', '', x, re.S) #strip speed
x = re.sub(r'<extensions>(.*?)</extensions>', '', x, re.S) # strip out extensions
```

then

```
#.kml header goes here
kmlTrack = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.ope......etc etc
```

then

```
buf = StringIO.StringIO(x)
for line in buf:
            if line is not None:
                    timm = re.search('time>(.*?)</time', line, re.S)
                    if timm is not None:
                            kmlTrack += ("          <when>"+ timm.group(1)+"</when>\n")
                            checkSumA =+ 1
buf = StringIO.StringIO(x)
for line in buf:
            if line is not None:
                    lat = re.search('lat="(.*?)" lo', line, re.S)
                    lon = re.search('lon="(.*?)"><ele>', line, re.S)
                    ele = re.search('<ele>(.*?)</ele>', line, re.S)
                    if lat is not None:
                            kmlTrack += ("          <gx:coord>"+ lon.group(1) + " " + lat.group(1) + " " + ele.group(1) + "</gx:coord>\n")
                            checkSumB =+ 1
if checkSumA == checkSumB:
            #put a footer on
            kmlTrack += """     </gx:Track></Placemark></Document></kml>"""
else:
            print ("checksum error")
            return None

with open("outFile.kml", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(kmlTrack)
return ("succsesful .kml file-write completed in :" + str(c.seconds) + " seconds.")
```

Once again, this is working but it is **very slow**. If anyone can see how to speed this up, please let me know! Cheers

---

**UPDATED**

thanks for suggestions, all.  I'm new to Python and appreciated hearing about profiling.  Found out about it. Added it to my script. and it looks like its down to one thing, 208 of the total time of 209 seconds to run, happen in one line. Here is a snip:

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 ....

 4052    0.013    0.000    0.021    0.000 StringIO.py:139(readline)
 8104    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 StringIO.py:38(_complain_ifclosed)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 StringIO.py:54(__init__)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 StringIO.py:65(__iter__)
 4052    0.010    0.000    0.033    0.000 StringIO.py:68(next)
 8101    0.018    0.000    0.078    0.000 re.py:139(search)
    4    0.000    0.000  208.656   52.164 re.py:144(sub)
 8105    0.016    0.000    0.025    0.000 re.py:226(_compile)
   35    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 rpc.py:149(debug)
    5    0.000    0.000    0.010    0.002 rpc.py:208(remotecall)
 ......
```

There are 4 calls of 52 seconds per call. cProfile says it happens on line number 144 but my script only goes to 94 lines.   How do i move on this? Thanks much.

Comment: Try with cStringIO? (Although I'd suspect the regexes on a 477K string myself; use a profiler instead of guessing.)

Comment: @Wooble +1 -- This is a not fruitful approach.  Do not guess. profile your code. http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: The best way to convert one xml format to another is with xml/xpath/xsl.

Comment: I also guess that repeatedly processing the same data is the performance problem, like you are doing with the regexes. Also, you probably want code that understands XML, because your code can break valid XML. For example, `'<foo\nbar="baz">'` is turned into `'<foobar="baz">'` in your first step.

Comment: Thanks Wooble, Jim, tdelaney and doomster. I have taken some schooling in cProfile (thanks to Jim's suggestion) and **UPDATED** the Q with a snip of the profile output.  it says it happens on line 144, but my script only goes to 94 lines?  i cant see _anything_ that would get called 4 times for 52 seconds each??what do you suggest to fix?

Comment: This means the calls to `re.sub` take the most time

Answer (score 3):

OK thanks to all. the cProfile showed it was a `re.sub` call, though i initially wasn't sure which one - though with some trial and error, it didnt take long to isolate it. The solution was to fix the `re.sub` from being a 'greedy' to a 'non-greedy' call.

So the old header strip call was `x = re.sub(r'<(.*)<trkseg>', '', x, re.S)  #strip header`
now becomes `x = re.sub(r'<?xml(.*?)<trkseg>', '', x, re.S) #strip header REALLY fast`.

It now finshes even heavy .gxp conversions in zero seconds.  What a difference a `?` makes !